# Как вывести большой объем данных на страницу в табличном виде?

Tags: javascript

Строк где-то тыс. 200-300, при выводе ошибка `Out of Memory`
Как лучше действовать?

Comment: Пагинация..............

Comment: 200-300К сразу никто не прочитает. Порционно..

Comment: @Rudi У меня такое ощущение, что это не строки, а пиксели картинки :) Просто `1920*1080 = 2073600` ))

Comment: @EzioMercer, думаете автор хранит картинку попиксельно? О.о

Comment: @De.Minov Вполне может быть, т.к. уже был такой вопрос, правда я не смог его найти, но суть была в том, чтобы из базы подтянуть все пиксели картинки и отобразить на канвасе :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, ужс какой.. Бедное всё, если кто-то додумается хранить 4k, 8k, и т.д..

Comment: Я не спрашиваю про прочитает или не прочитает, я спрашиваю можно или нельзя в браузере вывести все сразу?

Comment: @Freerade, вы спросили как лучше действовать, вам сказали, никто читать не будет => нет смысла выводить столько данных **за раз**, к тому же браузеру это тоже не понравится, ибо много элементов на странице не есть хорошо, по этому используется везде большой объём данных выводится по запросу или постранично, что по сути и есть пагинация.

Comment: @De.Minov, есть еще подход с виртуализацией.

Answer (score 3):

Погуглив ошибку, предполагаю, что проблема вызвана в `Node.js` (о чём не указывают метки..), решение есть следующее - увеличить объём памяти выделяемый для исполняемого файла.
Вот ответ с enSO - [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560292/7692602).
Важный момент, не указывайте всю доступную память, иначе можете положить систему.

---

> Как лучше действовать?

**Лучше** подумать о пользователе, никому не нужно 200-300k данных в таблице, вряд ли кто-то прочитает хотя бы 500.
Промолчу уже о том, что и браузеру это не особо понравится.

Лучшим вариантом, как уже предложил [@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420260/#comment2529016_1420260), будет использование пагинации.
Думаю [в интернете можно найти](https://www.google.com/search?q=pagination%20site) различные варианты реализации (JS, PHP, Node.js).

---

Погуглил ошибку для питона, вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963430/7692602) с SO, так же есть [статейка](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-memory-error/) об этой ошибке.
Опять же, в Питоне не шарю, но насколько понял из тех ссылок, что при использование 32-битного питона у вас ограничение на 2gb, а совет такой - использовать 64-битный.

Ну и опять же, пагинация, в чём суть, у вас есть массив, вы разбиваете его на части (допустим 500.000 на 10 частей и того по 50к в каждой), и просто ссылаетесь не на весь массив, а на части.
Уверен, что и на питоне можно это реализовать без проблем (если используете Django, то вот [статейка](https://prognote.ru/web-dev/back-end/python-django-pagination/)).

Comment: У меня с питоновского бека приходит здоровый массив и его надо отобразить, node.js я не пользуюсь

Comment: @Freerade, дополнил ответ